# Regarding slow performance of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse 3.7 indigo , the issue that I am facing is when I start my eclipse my machine gets too slow even the eclipse get hang some times in between  , the settings of my eclipse.ini file is below..

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

please advise how to overcome from this..!!

Comment: What is your machine configuration?

Comment: What version of java are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Change this values to the higher ones:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help? I mean, I don't know the specs of the machine you're on, but this is nice on less powerful machines.

[What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Check with the eclipse.ini file and add the following java parameters and values.

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xmn128m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss2m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

This worked for me. Might help.